# Weird order output. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
methods: {
    ShowWindow: function(QueryID) {
        this.$data.ID = QueryID;
        if(this.GetData())
        {
            console.log("asdasd")
        }
        document.querySelector("#EditWindow").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log(this.$data.RowData.name + "asdd");
        this.$refs.Title.SetName(this.$data.RowData.name + " " + this.$data.ID);
    },
    GetData: function(){
        const URI = localStorage.getItem("URI") + *URL part 2* + this.$data.ID;
        axios.get(URI, this.$parent.$data.optionsAxios).then((result) =>{
            this.$data.RowData = result.data;
            //console.log(result.data);
            console.log(this.$data.RowData.name);
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
        return true;
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.$data.ID = this.$route.params.UserID;
    this.ShowWindow(this.$data.ID);
    this.$data.TableName = this.$parent.TableName;
}
```

I don't have idea why my consol.log() performs in that order.

First i get answer from this

```
console.log("asdasd");
```

then

```
console.log(this.$data.RowData.name + "asdd");
```

and last

```
console.log(this.$data.RowData.name);
```

I don't know why it ignore what is inside this.GetData() and performs this last.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCLl.png)

Comment: Because you are making an _asynchronous_ request there …?

Comment: So, do you have any idea how I can perform GetData before rest of code? I tried await on this method but output order was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `GetData` makes an `async` request, you need to `await` it before proceeding so as to get a more predictable output.

```js
methods: {
    ShowWindow: async function(QueryID) {
      this.$data.ID = QueryID;
      try {
        const result = await this.GetData()

        this.$data.RowData = result.data;
        console.log(this.$data.RowData.name);

        if (result) {
          console.log("asdasd")
        }

        document.querySelector("#EditWindow").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log(this.$data.RowData.name + "asdd");
        this.$refs.Title.SetName(this.$data.RowData.name + " " + this.$data.ID);

      } catch(e) {
        console.log('error');
      }
    },
    GetData: function() {
      const URI = localStorage.getItem("URI") + * URL part 2 * +this.$data.ID;
      return axios.get(URI, this.$parent.$data.optionsAxios);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$data.ID = this.$route.params.UserID;
    this.ShowWindow(this.$data.ID);
    this.$data.TableName = this.$parent.TableName;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`axios.get(...)` is an asynchronous function and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). When the request is finished this promise will resolve and the `.then(...)` part is executed to process the result.

While the request is in progress (and thus we are waiting for a server response) the execution of the code continuous. It would be not really efficient if we are waiting for the (potentially slow) server response.